# Файл менеджер и Категории

Tags: android

Есть реальный телефон. В его Проводнике есть "Категории" (изображения, видео, аудио, документы, загрузки, установочные файлы).

В своем приложение я скачиваю файлы из сети. Они успешно создаются и я могу найти их в проводнике. (могу и во внутренее хранлище отправить, так и общедоступное)
Но они никак не появляются в этих "категориях" в проводнике.

У того же KateMobile, все что я качаю отправляется по разным папкам(изобржаение в одно место, документы в другое), но категории видят такие файлы.

Что надо сделать, чтобы пометить свой файл для категории?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для такой задачи нужен `MediaScannerConnection`
он и отвечает за индексацию файлов для категорий в Файловых Менеджерах

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient;
import android.net.Uri;

import java.io.File;

public class SingleMediaScanner implements MediaScannerConnectionClient {

    private MediaScannerConnection mMs;
    private File mFile;

    public SingleMediaScanner(Context context, File f) {
        mFile = f;
        mMs = new MediaScannerConnection(context, this);
        mMs.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
        mMs.scanFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath(), null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        mMs.disconnect();
    }

}


// использование 
SingleMediaScanner(application, myFile)
```